# How to use JavaScript to get element by class name and then split commas onto new lines?

Tags: javascript, jquery, split, getelementsbyclassname

Let's say I have this HTML output:

```
<h3 class="blog-post-title">
<a href="https://www.link1.com" class="blog-post-title-link">John Doe, MD</a>
</h3>

<h3 class="blog-post-title">
<a href="https://www.link2.com" class="blog-post-title-link">Jane Doe, MD</a>
</h3>

<h3 class="blog-post-title">
<a href="https://www.link3.com" class="blog-post-title-link">Jane Doe Smith, MD</a>
</h3>
```

How would I use a simple script to replace the comma and space inside each 'blog-post-title-link' class with a line break? So instead of looking like this:
**John Doe, MD**
**Jane Doe, MD**
**Jane Doe Smith, MD**

The output would be:
**John Doe
MD**
**Jane Doe
MD**
**Jane Doe Smith
MD**

**UPDATED NOTE: The names and the MD in the simple example above should not be hard-coded. Sorry I didn't mention that originally.**

Finally, if I wanted add a style to the split text so that the "MD" lines above appear in a different color, I'm wondering if I could use the same function and just use a `<span>` or `<div>` tag to wrap the split text rather than just a line break. Any help is much appreciated, as I don't have access to change the original text.

Comment: I would put both in a separate <p> tags so it's block level. Then, adjust the line-height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This queries all `blog-post-title-link` classes, replacing commas in their HTML with its following text, wrapped in a `div`:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.blog-post-title-link').forEach(function(obj) {
  obj.innerHTML = obj.innerHTML.replace(/,(.+)/, (_, s) => `<div>${s}</div>`);
});
```

To get a different color, you could style `a div` like this:

```
a div {
  color: red;
}
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.blog-post-title-link').forEach(function(obj) {
  obj.innerHTML = obj.innerHTML.replace(/,(.+)/, (_, s) => `<div>${s}</div>`);
});
```

```css
a div {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="blog-post-title">
<a href="https://www.link1.com" class="blog-post-title-link">John Doe, MD</a>
</h3>

<h3 class="blog-post-title">
<a href="https://www.link2.com" class="blog-post-title-link">Jane Doe, MD</a>
</h3>

<h3 class="blog-post-title">
<a href="https://www.link3.com" class="blog-post-title-link">Jane Doe Smith, MD</a>
</h3>
```

Here's the jQuery equivalent:

```
$('.blog-post-title-link').html((_, html) => 
  html.replace(/,(.+)/, (_, s) => `<div>${s}</div>`)
);
```

```js
$('.blog-post-title-link').html((_, html) => 
  html.replace(/,(.+)/, (_, s) => `<div>${s}</div>`)
);
```

```css
.blog-post-title div {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 class="blog-post-title">
<a href="https://www.link1.com" class="blog-post-title-link">John Doe, MD</a>
</h3>

<h3 class="blog-post-title">
<a href="https://www.link2.com" class="blog-post-title-link">Jane Doe, MD</a>
</h3>

<h3 class="blog-post-title">
<a href="https://www.link3.com" class="blog-post-title-link">Jane Doe Smith, MD</a>
</h3>
```

Comment: This is definitely the answer, although I'm wondering if I can target the class 'blog-post-title-link' instead of 'H3 a'

Comment: Thanks Rick, very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

use string.split with , as delimiter, then loop the array outputting every string on a new line.

```
let string = document.getElementById("myID").innerHTML;

let array = string.split(',');

let outStr = '';

array.foreach( (str) => {
    outStr += str + '\n';
});

document.getElementById("myID").innerHTML = outStr;
```

Comment: There are many more ways to select elements than `getElementById`. Considering there are no IDs in the OP's HTML, this might not be the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// find elements by className and do some operation on each of them
document.querySelectorAll('.blog-post-title').forEach(node => {
  // take content of the node
  const content = node.innerText;

  // split it by ,
  const splitContent = content.split(',');

  // create name element
  const nameEl = document.createElement("div");
  nameEl.innerText = splitContent[0];

  // create position element
  const positionEl = document.createElement("div");
  positionEl.innerText = splitContent[1];
  positionEl.style = "color: red"; // add some styling

  // clear existing node
  node.innerHTML = '';
  // append created elements to existing node
  node.appendChild(nameEl);
  node.appendChild(positionEl);
})
```

```html
<h3 class="blog-post-title">
  <a href="https://www.link1.com" class="blog-post-title-link">John Doe, MD</a>
</h3>

<h3 class="blog-post-title">
  <a href="https://www.link2.com" class="blog-post-title-link">Jane Doe, MD</a>
</h3>

<h3 class="blog-post-title">
  <a href="https://www.link3.com" class="blog-post-title-link">Jane Doe Smith, MD</a>
</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would iterate through the links in heading. Split the text at comma and then put them together again but wraping the second element in a span. Then you can use css to style the span.

```js
$('h3 a').each(function(){
   let txt = $(this).text().split(',');
   $(this).html(txt[0] + '<span class="position">'+ txt[1] + '</span>');
});
```

```css
.position{display:block;color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 class="blog-post-title">
<a href="https://www.link1.com" class="blog-post-title-link">John Doe, MD</a>
</h3>

<h3 class="blog-post-title">
<a href="https://www.link2.com" class="blog-post-title-link">Jane Doe, MD</a>
</h3>

<h3 class="blog-post-title">
<a href="https://www.link3.com" class="blog-post-title-link">Jane Doe Smith, MD</a>
</h3>
```

Comment: This puts more than just the "MD" in the `span` tag. I'd have to assume the browser is helping you out by assuming the `span` is closed so the `a` tag can be closed.

Comment: The span tag IS closed and it is inside the A tag. The only "more than just MD" getting in span is a space. Which can be trimmed.

Comment: You code says that `txt[1]` == "MD</a>", which you include inside the `span` tag. You don't split out the `a` tag.

Comment: No it doesn't. You are missing the selector that includes 'a'. Which means it is only selecting the 'TEXT' (not html) inside the a tag.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd split the lines.

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("blog-post-title-link");

let length = x.length;

for (var i = 0; i < length; i++){
    let text = x[i].textContent;
    text = text.replace(", ", "<br>");
    x[i].innerHTML = text;
    console.log(x[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple "replace" should make this work.

```
var htmlText = document.getElementById("testing").innerHTML;
var newText = htmlText.split(", MD").join("\n<div class='newStyle'>MD</div>")
document.getElementById("testing").innerHTML = newText;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gnyf76r0/1/

Comment: You have hard-coded MD in there assuming it will always be MD?

Comment: @NawedKhan, that's what the example shows. If they want something else, they should have explicitly said the "MD" could be anything. YAGNI.

Comment: If that is the case why not hard code the John Doe too? Based on your logic if the name could be Mary Smith then they should have explicitly mention. lol

Comment: @NawedKhan, my code doesn't need to specify "John Doe". Adding that is unnecessary. Since the OP specifically stated they wanted to alter the "MD" portion, that is necessary.